# Getting started with Leap Motion

Tags: javascript, leap-motion, delphi, smart-mobile-studio

I just got my Leap Motion controller. But i must admit that i dont know how to get the basic initialisation up and running in SmartMS !?

I have included the leapmotionts-1.0.9+8391.js from https://github.com/logotype/LeapMotionTS and added the leap.Core to the uses clause of my project. Sms accepts a initialisation like this :

```
Controller:=New JController();
```

But i have no idea on how to set up the eventlistener ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some more fixes and now it works!

To try a demo, download the www folder and open index.html:
https://github.com/andremussche/AndrewsDelphiStuff/blob/master/Smart/LeapMotion/www/index.html

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the generated library and re-generated the javascript too (so it works in browsers too)
https://github.com/andremussche/AndrewsDelphiStuff/tree/master/Smart/LeapMotion

Example code:

```
uses
  leap.core;

{$R 'leapmotionts-1.0.9+8391.js'}

  var j = new JController;
  j.addEventListener(JLeapEvent.LEAPMOTION_CONNECTED,
    procedure(event: JLeapEvent)
    begin
      do something
    end);
```

Comment: This is not working for me. The event is not getting called ?